# cannot compile JNI project using cygwin

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cygwin

while trying to compile JNI project using cygwin I used `./ndk-build` . But got `-bash: ./ndk-build: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied` error. How to resolve this issue.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to run **ndk-build.cmd**. You don't need to disable cygwin for that.

Answer (score 0):

The partition has been mounted as user and as noexec. You can run the command below, copy your project to the /tmp folder and try your command again.

```
mount -o remount,exec /tmp
```

If that lets you compile than you need to find the mounted device your folder was on and alter it to defaults by editing `/etc/fstab`